# The good practice for defining a reusable resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been writing a CAD-style program in .Net, for this I have to have a lot of `Brushes` and `Custom DashStyles`.

So far I have defined them in a `static` class. for example:

```
public static readonly Brush GridBrushInModel = Brushes.DarkGray;
```

Now I can use the brush whenever I want. I have also *Freezed* them though.

My question is, is this the way this should be done? Or there are better ways? For example defining in `ResourceDictionary`? How it is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared resources in a WPF application are typically stored as a `ResourceDictionary`. Each dictionary should have its own XAML file (if you wish to split up your resources).

They are pretty easy to define:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyCoolBrush" Color="Black"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note that I gave the element a `x:Key` attribute. This is what you use to reference the resource later.

Finally, you have to *merge* the dictionary into the using code. This can be done at any level, though its most commonly done in the `Window.Resources` or in `App.xaml`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MyBrushes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Once you have them, you can reference them in XAML like this:

```
<Grid Background={StaticResource MyCoolBrush}/>
```

Comment: Since I'm going to use them in code-behind to draw lines and stuff, I will have to access the resources in code-behind. Can this be less performant than my current way?

Comment: @Vahid Accessing a dictionary is very fast (and thats what the `Resources` property is in code). Not quite as fast as direct access to a static global, but still very fast. In general, you shouldn't be using this stuff in code-behind enough for it to matter. You may want to consider giving the code-behind access to the resources via DependencyProperties instead, so the XAML defines which resources are used.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you give me an example of doing this using DependencyProperties or point me to one on SO?

Comment: @Vahid You know how to create a Dependency Property, right? Once you have that you just put `MyDepProp="{StaticResource MyCoolBrush}"` in the XAML for that control.

Comment: I know but I'm drawing on `DrawingContext` for example `dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Settings.GridBrushInModel , 1), p1, p2);`, how can I use the DP you are suggesting here?

Comment: @Vahid Ah, just replace `Settings.GridBrushInModel` with that DP (`MyDepProp`)

Comment: Thanks, but then I will have to define the DP in every class that I'm drawing a line with that brush?

Comment: @Vahid The theory would be that you want to be able to give a control a specific brush each time you have an instance of that control (that is, that it could change). So good design dictates that you do exactly what you described. In your situation, where you are guaranteeing that you are using the same resource each time, you could just directly access the `Resources` dictionary. Its just not as flexible later.

Comment: I assume that it is very hard to stick to good design guidelines in these types of programs.

Comment: @Vahid It gets easier with practice :). Its a **ton** easier when you start with good design, instead of having to do massive amounts of refactoring. I don't see anything in the general program concept that would dictate a poor design.

Comment: I know I've written a full-working software and yet I feel I know nothing about OOP.

Comment: @Vahid You'll get there. Theres a reason the usual advice is to "Throw the first one away" (Not that anyone actually *does* that, but most probably *should*). I actually got the opportunity to do that one time, and my second attempt was **way** better

Comment: Don't tell me I should throw it away too! I'm planning to sell it :D After thoroughly debugging it though :p

Comment: @Vahid Practical realities mean that you almost never get to throw the first one away :). In my case I had to completely rewrite the system due to a platform/language/scope change. I already had found all the "gotchas" by writing the first system, so I was able to account for them in the second one without ruining the design. Its a very uncommon situation to be in, but one that was thoroughly enjoyable!

Comment: I completely get what you mean, this has happened to me too but on a very smaller scale.